# Custom Core Data entities

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

How does one create a Core Data Entity that has custom objects within it?

E.g. An entity that has the possibility of holding, e.g. images, audio clips, a custom godzilla object.

How are these saved and loaded as well? Using NSData?

Comment: check the first answer to this question: [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007588/core-data-error-myclass-encodewithcoder-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-insta/6007924#6007924)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to use a 'transformable' attribute. See the Core Data documentation here for more information:

[Non-Standard Persistent Attributes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html)

Answer (score 1):

If the custom classes conform to the NSCoding protocol you can make use of [Transformable Attributes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001919-SW1). A short quote from Apple's chapter [Non-Standard Persistent Attributes pf Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001919-SW1):

> The idea behind transformable
>   attributes is that you access an
>   attribute as a non-standard type, but
>   behind the scenes Core Data uses an
>   instance of NSValueTransformer to
>   convert the attribute to and from an
>   instance of NSData. Core Data then
>   stores the data instance to the
>   persistent store.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can do it using NSData

for example converting a UIImage to NSData

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"some.png"];

NSData *dataObj = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0);
```

and then you can save it in the directory using

```
[dataObj writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];
```

Here fileName is the path of file in the directory

Comment: But using writeToFile on NSData won't store it into a NSManagedObject or core data entity like was asked